# Is it possible to override a configs property in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

For my swarm deployed C# docker services I use `docker config` to store my appsettings. This works fine but I am trying to set up some integration tests to run outside of a swarm, using a docker-compose override I am able to override all of the properties I need to get this working with the exception of the `configs` section. A typical docker-compose would look like:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyService/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "1"
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik-net
        - traefik.http.services.myservice.loadbalancer.server.port=80
        - traefik.http.routers.myservice.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.myservice.entrypoints=web-secured
        - traefik.http.routers.myservice.service=myservice
        - traefik.http.routers.myservice.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
    configs:
      - source: prs_appsettings
        target: /app/appsettings.json
configs:
  prs_appsettings:
    external: true
networks:
  traefik-net:
    external: true
```

What I would like to do is effectively remove the `configs` section in an override and provide appsettings.json through a volume mount but I'm not sure how.

Is this possible? I suppose an alternative would be to have a base without `configs` then prod and test overrides but I'd rather keep my original docker-compose unaltered.

TIA

Rich

Comment: can you use environment variables?

Comment: How would that work @DanielA.White?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleaner way to do this is to maintain `compose.yml` (and `compose.override.yml`) for `docker compose up` type deployments and have a `compose.stack.yml` that is used for stack deployments.

This lets you keep a base `compose.yml` that is clean and describe all the things about your services that are common to compose and stack deployments.  `compose.override.yml` adds any local development specific things (volume bindings, published ports) and `compose.stack.yml` adds all the configs, secrets and other swarm things.